# BotFramework Accessing userData within Form Flow

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to access userData from within a formFlow form.  The only way I have been able to do it is to create a static context object on my FormFlow class `public static IDialogContext context { get; set; }` as shown below.

```
    public static IDialogContext context { get; set; }

    public static IForm<Reservation> BuildForm()
    {
        string userName = String.Empty;
        context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("Name", out userName);
        return new FormBuilder<Reservation>()
            .Field(new FieldReflector<Reservation>(nameof(Reservation.Name))
                .SetActive((state) =>
                {
                   //StateClient stateClient =  activity.GetStateClient();
                    //BotData userData = stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
                    state.Name = userName;
                    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.Name);
```

Then in my RootDialog I set it before I call the form.

```
case ReservationOption:
                    ReservationForm.context = context;
                    context.Call(FormDialog.FromForm<Reservation>(ReservationForm.BuildForm,
                    FormOptions.PromptInStart), this.ReservationFormComplete);

                    break;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Perfect, I was just thinking about this same problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a better way to do that would be to instantiate the `FormDialog` using `new` instead of the `FromForm` method. That way, will allow you to send an instance of the form state (in your case `Reservation`) pre-filled with any value you already have in the state (e.g. `userName`)

```
var form = new FormDialog<Reservation>(
               new Reservation(userName),
               ReservationForm.BuildForm,
               FormOptions.PromptInStart,
               null);

context.Call(form, this.ReservationFormComplete)
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureBot/blob/master/AzureBot.Services.VMs/Dialogs/VMDialog.cs#L151-L157) is a sample doing just that.

Comment: Thank you .. so simple I overlooked adding a constructor to Reservation Class to pass the context to.

Comment: Great. While setting the context would definitely work, the advantage of sending the values for the properties would be better in the sense that the FormFlow will skip them if the "state" property has a value set

Comment: Gotcha, so just do a  this.Name = name in the constructor and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ezequiel Jadib  I thought I would post the whole solution here for others.

So in the RootDialog I am instantiating the dialog using new and passing in the context to the Reservation Model.

```
var form = new FormDialog<Reservation>(
new Reservation(context),
ReservationForm.BuildForm,
FormOptions.PromptInStart,
null);
```

In my Reservation Class (My Model) I added a constructor that took in an IDialogContext object (and adding a `using Microsfot.Bot.Build.Dialogs;` to the top)  Creating a property to hold it with a private setter.

```
    public class Reservation
{
    public IDialogContext Context { get; private set; }
    public Reservation(IDialogContext context )
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }
```

I am then able to access my entire context (userData, ConversationData, etc...) from inside the formflow in order to check it and ignore questions that would be repeat.

```
 state.Context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("Name", out userName);
 state.Name = userName;
```